# Is the new way of counting badges on user profiles intentional?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page

The new profile page layout has some attractive and some not-so-attractive new features, IMHO, but among the not-so-attractive to me is the new way of counting badges:

[image: badges]

It now counts how many types of badges a user has attained rather than the actual number (counting multiples of the same badge).  I just need to know whether to report it as a bug or protest ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a bug. It doesn't jibe with the count shown on your [flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/164012/daniel/flair), or next to your name at the top of the screen.

If the intention is to represent the number of badge *types* you've managed to obtain, then it should say that (but I doubt that was the intent - the old page had exactly the same wording, but counted properly).

Comment: This might have been a bug then, but looking at it three years later it looks the same way... When was it decided that it was actually a feature?

Answer (score 6):

This was definitely not intentional, a fix will go out for the top count in the next build.

Answer (score -2):

It puts how many of each next to the specific badge. Definitely much clearer to see. I don't see this as a bug, more of an improvement

Comment: I wasn't referring to the "how many of each next to the specific badge" feature; that feature one was in the old profile page design.  I'm only referring to the badge count I circled with a nice red freehand circle in the screenshot.

Comment: Yep - I saw that. Seems much clearer this way - 61 different types of badges. And if you want to know how many in total, you just add up the individual ones.

Comment: Eh... If you want to count *types*, multiply rows by columns - 52 to a page, etc. That's quite a bit faster than sitting there adding up all the xN values.

Comment: now I'm puzzled - I wouldn't want to add up total badges - it has them on my flair. So at a glance on flair I know my total, and on this page I have the total types. Simple.